Why am I getting a Python Syntax error when creating a python-based stored procedure?
I have migrated a Python script that was running on my local machine to run in Snowflake. I have tested the Python code by itself and it runs as expected. When I try to create a stored procedure with the python logic inside the stored procedure, I am returned the error:
 File "_udf_code.py", line 1
    CREATE PROCEDURE prc_industry_data_quality()
           ^^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
 in function PYTHON_WORKSHEET with handler main

Here is the code that is causing the error:
CREATE PROCEDURE prc_industry_data_quality()
  RETURNS TABLE
  LANGUAGE PYTHON
  RUNTIME_VERSION = '3.8'
  PACKAGES = ('snowflake-snowpark-python', 'pandas')
  HANDLER = 'main'
AS
$$
import pandas as pd
from snowflake.snowpark.functions import col
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

database = "DEV_NDVM533_DB"
schema = "CENTRAL_MDM_020_STG"

def return_pd_dataframes(session):

     # SQL queries
    query1 = """
SELECT 
    POLICY_REFERENCE,
    SECTION_REFERENCE,
    CASE
        WHEN SOURCE_SYSTEM IS NULL THEN ORIGINATING_SOURCE_SYSTEM
        ELSE SOURCE_SYSTEM
    END AS SYSTEM,
    AUDIT_CREATE_DATE_TIME,
    INDUSTRY_CODE,
    INDUSTRY,
    INDUSTRY_CODE_QUALIFIER
FROM 
    test_sect_ext;
"""
    
    query2 = """
    SELECT 
        NAICS_CODE AS INDUSTRY_CODE,
        NAICS_TITLE,
        VALID_FROM,
        VALID_TO 
    FROM 
        CENTRAL_MDM.NAICS_6_DIGIT;
    """
    
    query3 = "SELECT * FROM stg_industry_data_quality;"

    query4 = "SELECT * FROM stg_industry_data_quality_log;"
    
    # Execute the queries and create pandas DataFrames
    query_df = session.sql(query1)
    query_df = query_df.to_pandas()
    
    naics_codes_df = session.sql(query2)
    naics_codes_df = naics_codes_df.to_pandas()
    
    prev_data_df = session.sql(query3)
    prev_data_df = prev_data_df.to_pandas()

    log_df = session.sql(query4)
    log_df = log_df.to_pandas()

    return query_df, naics_codes_df, prev_data_df, log_df


def preProcessData(data):
    subset = ['POLICY_REFERENCE', 'SYSTEM', 'INDUSTRY_CODE', 'INDUSTRY', 'INDUSTRY_CODE_QUALIFIER']

    data['POLICY_REFERENCE'] = data['POLICY_REFERENCE'].astype('str')
    data['AUDIT_CREATE_DATE_TIME'] = pd.to_datetime(data['AUDIT_CREATE_DATE_TIME'])
    data['SYSTEM'] = data['SYSTEM'].astype('str')
    data['INDUSTRY_CODE'] = data['INDUSTRY_CODE'].astype('str')
    data['INDUSTRY'] = data['INDUSTRY'].astype('str')
    data['INDUSTRY_CODE'] = data['INDUSTRY_CODE'].astype('str')
    data['INDUSTRY_CODE'] = data['INDUSTRY_CODE'].replace({'None': None})
    data['INDUSTRY_CODE_QUALIFIER'] = data['INDUSTRY_CODE_QUALIFIER'].astype('str')
    data['INDUSTRY_CODE_QUALIFIER'] = data['INDUSTRY_CODE_QUALIFIER'].replace({'None': None})
    data.drop_duplicates(subset= subset, keep="first", inplace=True)
    
    return data

# Evaluates if the value in a column is Null
def isNull(row, column): # For Industry, column = 'Industry_Code'
        if row[column] is None:
            return True
        else:
            return False

# Evaluates if the value in a column is found in the NAICS code lookup table - if so, returns True
def isInLookup(row, column, lookuptable, lookupcolumn):
    if row[column] in lookuptable[lookupcolumn].values:
         return True
    else:
        return False

# Evaluate if the value in a column conforms to validity rules (within an allowed date range)
def isValid(row):
    if row['IS_IN_LOOKUP'] == True:
        if row['AUDIT_CREATE_DATE_TIME'] >= row['VALID_FROM'] and row['AUDIT_CREATE_DATE_TIME'] <= row['VALID_TO']:
            return True
        else:
            return False
    else:
        return False


def addIsValidColumn(data, lookup_table):
    """Applies the isValid function to the main dataset by joining the data with the lookup table 
    to allow comparison of ['AuditCreateDateTime']with ['Valid From'] and ['Valid To'] columns"""

    # left join the lookup table onto the data
    result_data = data.copy()
    merged_df = data.merge(lookup_table, on='INDUSTRY_CODE', how='left')

    # Apply the is_valid function to each row and create the 'IsValid' column
    merged_df['IS_VALID'] = merged_df.apply(isValid, axis=1)

    # Create a new DataFrame that includes only 'PolicyReference' and 'IsValid' columns
    policy_validity = merged_df[['POLICY_REFERENCE', 'IS_VALID']]

    # Join the 'IsValid' information into the copy of the original data on 'PolicyReference' to not change the df's structure
    result_data = result_data.merge(policy_validity, on='POLICY_REFERENCE', how='left')

    return result_data

# Returns the reason for the exception
def Reason(row):
    if row['IS_NULL'] == True:
        return 'Data Missing'
    if row['IS_IN_LOOKUP'] == False:
        return 'Data Not In Lookup'
    if row['IS_VALID'] == False:
        return 'Invalid'
    else:
        return 'No Exception Found'
    

# Evaluates if a row (policy) in the data has been loaded before in the previous iteration. If so, returns True
def scannedBefore(row, prev_data):
    prev_policies = prev_data['POLICY_REFERENCE'].tolist()
    return row['POLICY_REFERENCE'] in prev_policies

def fixedReferences(prev_data, new_data):
    """Returns policies that were not fixed in the last run but are fixed in the current run"""

        # Filter for where 'Was Fixed'== 'False' in prev_data and == True in current data
    if not prev_data.empty:
        prev_data_filtered = prev_data[prev_data['WAS_FIXED'] == False]
        current_data_filtered = new_data[new_data['WAS_FIXED'] == True]
        # Find the common policy references between previous and current data
        fixed_references = set(prev_data_filtered['POLICY_REFERENCE']).intersection(set(current_data_filtered['POLICY_REFERENCE']))
    else:
        fixed_references = []
    return fixed_references

# Changed with Sean
def wasFixed(row, prev_data):
    """Evaluates if a row that was already in the previous iteration has been fixed."""
    
    prev_row = prev_data.loc[prev_data['POLICY_REFERENCE'] == row['POLICY_REFERENCE']]
    scanned_before = scannedBefore(row, prev_data)
    return scanned_before and prev_row['REASON'].iloc[0] != 'No Exception Found' and row['REASON'] == 'No Exception Found'


def ingestDate(row, prev_data):
    """Returns the current datetime if the row is not found in the previous iteration of data 
    i.e. it has just been ingested"""

    if 'INGEST_DATE' in row:
        if pd.isna(row['INGEST_DATE']):
            return datetime.now().date()
        else:
            return row['INGEST_DATE']
    else:
        return datetime.now().date()


def fixDate(row, fixed_references):
    """Returns the date that the 'Was_Fixed' column was recorded as being set to True"""
    if row['POLICY_REFERENCE'] in list(fixed_references) and 'FIX_DATE' in row and pd.isnull(row['FIX_DATE']):
        return datetime.now().date()
    elif 'FIX_DATE' in row and pd.notna(row['FIX_DATE']):
        return row['FIX_DATE']
    else:
        return None

def timeToFix(row):
    """Returns the time taken to fix an exception(in days)"""

    if row['FIX_DATE'] is not None:
        return int((row['FIX_DATE'] - row['INGEST_DATE']).days)
    else:
        return None


def updateLog(log_df, data):
    most_recent_date = data['INGEST_DATE'].max()

    if not log_df.empty:
        iteration = log_df['ITERATION'].max() + 1
    else:
        iteration = 1
    log_df.loc[iteration, 'ITERATION'] = iteration
    log_df.loc[iteration, 'REFRESH_DATE'] = datetime.now()
    log_df.loc[iteration, 'INVALID_COUNT'] = len(data[(data['IS_VALID'] == False) | (data['IS_VALID'] == None) | (data['IS_NULL'] == True) | (data['IS_IN_LOOKUP'] == False)])
    log_df.loc[iteration, 'RESOLVED_COUNT'] = len(data[data['WAS_FIXED'] == True])
    log_df.loc[iteration, 'NEW_EXCEPTIONS'] = ((data['INGEST_DATE'] == most_recent_date) & (data['REASON'].isin(['Data Missing', 'Data Not In Lookup', 'Invalid']))).sum()

    return log_df

def addAdditionalColumns(data, column, lookup_table, prev_data):
    """Applies the above functions to each row to create columns with logic behind them to be used in the data quality dashboard"""
    new_data = data.copy()
    
    new_data['IS_NULL'] = new_data.apply(lambda row: isNull(row, 'INDUSTRY_CODE'), axis=1) # working
    new_data['IS_IN_LOOKUP'] = new_data.apply(lambda row: isInLookup(row, 'INDUSTRY_CODE', lookup_table, 'INDUSTRY_CODE'), axis=1) # working
    new_data = addIsValidColumn(new_data, lookup_table) # working
    new_data['REASON'] = new_data.apply(lambda row: Reason(row), axis=1) # working
    new_data['INGEST_DATE'] = new_data.apply(lambda row: ingestDate(row, prev_data), axis=1) # working
    new_data['WAS_FIXED'] = new_data.apply(lambda row: wasFixed(row, prev_data), axis=1) # working
    if not prev_data.empty:
        fixed_references = fixedReferences(prev_data, new_data)
    else:
        fixed_references = []
    new_data['FIX_DATE'] = new_data.apply(lambda row: fixDate(row, fixed_references), axis=1) # working
    new_data['TIME_TO_FIX'] = new_data.apply(lambda row: timeToFix(row), axis=1) # working
        
    return new_data

def main(session: snowpark.Session):
    session.sql("USE DATABASE dev_ndvm533_db").collect()
    session.sql("USE SCHEMA central_mdm_020_stg").collect()
    query, lookup_table, prev_data, log = return_pd_dataframes(session)
    query = preProcessData(query)
    transformed_data = addAdditionalColumns(query, 'INDUSTRY_CODE', lookup_table, prev_data)
    log_df = log
    log_df = updateLog(log, transformed_data)

    # Convert transformed pandas DataFrame to Snowpark DataFrame
    snowpark_df = session.create_dataframe(transformed_data)
    snowpark_log = session.create_dataframe(log_df)
    
    # Write the Snowpark DataFrame to Snowflake tables
    snowpark_df.write.mode("overwrite").save_as_table("stg_industry_data_quality")
    snowpark_log.write.mode("append").save_as_table("stg_industry_data_quality_log")

    return snowpark_log.limit(10)

result = main(session)
$$;



I have tried double checking that the python logic is within the $$

Your file is apparently an SQL file, but you seem to be executing the whole thing as Python code…?!

As @deceze notes, CREATE PROCEDURE is a SQL statement. SQL statements should be executed in SQL worksheets. Python worksheets should be used with Python code only. Use the Deploy button on the Python worksheet to transform the Python code to a CREATE PROCEDURE SQL statement and deploy. See https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowpark/python/python-worksheets for more details on the process.
